# Bios update for FoxConn 2AB1 1.00 Motherboard System BIOS 6.04

Tags: windows-10, bios, motherboard, firmware

Hey all this is for a HP Pavilion ELITE HPE-410f PC, want to update the bios, not sure if even available to do so current version is at 6.04.  Want to upgrade ram/processor so need bios updated if possible.  Scoured the net to no avail.  AMI website only has firmware download tools that do not recognize bios version on pc, tried all possible updaters, even with command line version, does not seem to be the correct updater at all.  All other links to this computer/bios update/ motherboard are dead ends.

The Foxconn website is entirely Chinese mostly with English translations mentions nothing of motherboards, AMI website updates all seem to be for different motherboard.  HP website is the worst, no support whatsoever.

Let me know if you guys have any leads on the bios firmware update and if its past 6.04.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Where did you find this BIOS version 6.04? As far as I can find, the BIOS wasn't updated since 2018.

Comment: I fixed the numerous spelling errors within your question.  In the future, please take the time, to resolve those yourself. The errors were with words that shouldn't have been spell incorrectly.

Comment: The bios version 6.04 is what is currently on the motherboard.  This computer has sat a while and the bios was not updated.

Comment: Thank you Ram hound. My specific problem is there is no information as to a bios update or if one even exists.